# Pyx12 Tigershark EDI Mapping Information Request

Tags: python, xml-parsing, edi, x12

Good morning,

Im working with https://github.com/jdavisp3/TigerShark

to convert edi files (835 claim responses) into XML with the objective to export into a database.

I am able to use the parsers and "navigate" into it using the facades. (example below to view the claims information using the facades.

```
from tigershark.parsers import M835_5010_X221_A1
from tigershark.facade.f835 import F835_5010
from tigershark.parsers.M835_5010_X221_A1 import parsed_835
j = M835_5010_X221_A1.parsed_835
def setUp(j):
    with open('file.dat') as f:

        parsed = parsed_835.unmarshall(f.read().strip())

    z = F835_5010(parsed).facades[0]
    zi = z.claims_overview

    print(zi)

setUp(j)
```

My problem is that I'm stuck in the mapping part, any of you guys with experience using this package could bring some light into it?

Thanks!

Comment: "My problem is that I'm stuck in the mapping part." 

It may be helpful to know what you are stuck on. What problems are you having?

Comment: @KevinR. Im trying to use the map part of the packagebut the documentation is not helping me, im looking for someone who had use this package and can bring some information.